# C++ Reverse Array

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

In C++, I need to:

- Read in a string from user input and place it into a char array [done]
- Then pass that array to a function [done]
- The function is supposed to reverse the order of characters [problem!]
- Then, back in the `main()`, it displays that original array with the newly reversed characters.

I'm having trouble creating the function that actually does the reversing because I have some restrictions:

- I cannot have any local array
  variables.
- No pointers either

My function is only passing in the original array ie:

```
void reverse(char word[])
```

**EDIT:** Here's my code base so far:

```
void reverse(char word[]);

void main() 
{
  char word[MAX_SIZE];

  cout << endl << "Enter a word : ";
  cin >> word; 
  cout << "You entered the word " << word << endl;

  reverse(word); 

  cout << "The word in reverse order is " << word << endl;
}

void reverse(char myword[]) 
{
  int i, temp;
  j--;

  for(i=0;i<(j/2);i++) 
  {
    temp      = myword[i];
    myword[i] = myword[j];
    myword[j] = temp; 

    j--; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Those restrictions sound pretty arbitrary for the real world.

Comment: Greg, yes - it sure is homework and I feel the same way!

Comment: j doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. also I'm sure someone would like to have the answer marked as an answer

Answer (score 10):

Despite this looking quite homeworky, may I suggest:

```
void reverse(char word[])
{
    int len=strlen(word);
    char temp;
    for (int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
            temp=word[i];
            word[i]=word[len-i-1];
            word[len-i-1]=temp;
    }
}
```

or, better yet, the classic XOR implementation:

```
void reverse(char word[])
{
    int len=strlen(word);
    for (int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
        word[i]^=word[len-i-1];
        word[len-i-1]^=word[i];
        word[i]^=word[len-i-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @dazedandconfused: I've seen this question in C++ related job interviews.  I agree with Greg.  It is important you understand how his solution works.  On a related note, in the real world one could simply use the standard reverse algorithm to reverse the order of characters in the array, i.e. std::reverse(word, word + strlen(word)).  I wouldn't give that simple solution to your teacher, however. :)

Comment: Using XOR will be far slower than swapping using a temp object.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'll point you toward a solution without just giving you the answer.

Your `reverse` function can modify the `word` that is passed in. One thing you'll need to know is how long the word is (so you'll know how many letters to reverse), you can get this from the `strlen()` function. If you're not permitted to use pointers, then you can use a local `int` index variable.

Comment: So, should I convert my char array into a string to use the strlen() function?

Comment: A string is exactly the same as a character array. You can call strlen(word).

Comment: Thanks Greg, I was getting thrown off by a 'warning' that it was giving me. It was building just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
void showContentVector(std::vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void dfs(int current, int previous, std::vector<int>& input, std::vector<int>& visited)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    int item=input[current];
    for(int next=(current+1); next<input.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs(next, current, input, visited);
    }
    if(current==input.size()-1)
    {
        input.clear();
    }
    input.push_back(item);
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    const int maximumSize=5;
    std::vector<int> values={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
    std::cout<<"Before, values <- ";
    showContentVector(values);
    dfs(0, -1, values, visited);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"After, values <- ";
    showContentVector(values);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Before, values <- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
After, values <- 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
```

Answer (score -1):

If we are talking C-Strings, then your function should be

```
void reverse(char word[],size_t wordlen)
```

First answer from the same question (this is a dupe from [Reverse a sentence in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080449/reverse-a-sentence-in-c/1080463#1080463))

This doesn't do what you are looking for, but gets you quite close!

```
 int ReverseString(char *rev)
         {
            if(*rev!='\0')
            {
               ReverseString(rev + 1);
               putchar(*rev);//change this.
            }

            return 1;
         }
```

Credits to @devinb.

Comment: Sorry, that is another restriction I forgot to mention - not supposed to use pointers either.

Comment: This doesn't return the reversed array, as requested by the question.

Comment: @Greg Where does it say that must return reversed array?

Comment: @Tom: "back in the main(), it displays that original array with the newly reversed characters"

Comment: I'll leave that for you to take up with @dazedandconfused.

Comment: @Greg: Question states: void reverse(char word[])

Comment: Correct. Below is what I have so far. It doesn't actually build unless I pass an int along with the char (for j). When I do that though, it only swaps the first and last characters.

void reverse(char word[]);

void main()
{

  char word[MAX_SIZE];

  cout << endl << "Enter a word : ";
  cin >> word;
  cout << "You entered the word " << word << endl;

  reverse(word);

  cout << "The word in reverse order is " << word << endl;

}

void reverse(char myword[])
{
int i,temp;
 j--;
 for(i=0;i<(j/2);i++)
 {
  temp=myword[i];
  myword[i]=myword[j];
  myword[j]=temp;
  j--;
 }
}

Comment: Ive put this into your question. Do that in the future, so that everyone sees your advance (edit your question)

Answer (score -2):

//this program helps you to find maximum and minimum number in an array

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{int max;

    int a[5]={12,1,0,4,5};
 int min=a[0];
    int i=1;
    max=a[0];

    while(i<=4)
    {
              if (max < a[i])
              max=a[i];
              if (min > a[i])
              min=a[i];
              i++;

    }
              cout << min <<"\n";
              cout << max;
              getch();
              return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really what the author of this question was asking for - they wanted to reverse an array.