# Reverse a character array

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Reverse Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128985/c-reverse-array)

How can I reverse a character array? Like this:

```
char word1[10] = "this"; 
char word2[10] = word1[10] // in reverse 
cout<<word2; // I want it to output "siht"
```

Comment: what array word type is?

Comment: @moon: The tag suggests C++ ;)

Comment: That looks like homework ^^ Try to code the fact that word2[i] = word1[sizeWord1 - i - 1], in good C++ ^^

Comment: ok @elusive thanx buddy i did't look at the tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple loop (since i do not know the exact type of `word1` and `word2`)?

```
for (int i = 0, k = 9; i < 10; i++, k--) {
    word2[k] = word1[i];
}
```

I highly suggest that you use `std::string` instead of `char`. There are plenty of answers on how to do this with `std::string` here.

Comment: If i write cout<<word2; it gives me the address not the word

Comment: this was actually a good idea, i made it work with char array

Comment: Not correct, since it will likely print garbage (un-initialized indexes on the original array) until it gets \0, then stops.

Answer (score 8):

```
std::string word1 = "this";
std::string word2 = word1;
std::reverse(word2.begin(), word2.end());
std::cout << word2;
```

Comment: i know to do it with string, but this one i didn't know, thx

Comment: @mira: Which type _is_ it, if not `string`?

Comment: @elusive it is char word1[10]

Comment: Or just: `std::string word2(word1.rbegin(), word1.rend());` - no need to `std::reverse` it later.

Comment: This is arguably better than the accepted answer because it does not use a hand-written loop.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard something like the following:

1. Copy `word1` to `word2`, using `std::copy`
2. `std::reverse` with word2 begin to end

and now `word2` contains reverse, can't say more without knowing types.

Comment: @ronag, it was there in front of my eyes, and I missed it.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a string reverse function to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

If word1 and word2 are char arrays, then nope. If instead word1 and word2 were some sort of object with a capacity of 10, you could just override the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int, char**) {
    std::string word1 = "beef";
    std::string word2(word1.rbegin(), word1.rend());
    std::cout << word2;
}
```

http://ideone.com/drunA

Answer (score 0):

```
std::reverse_copy(word1, word1+10, word2);
```

Comment: That would reverse the trailing \0, making it the first character. The result should be obvious.

Comment: Indeed. But that doesn't seem to be a problem in OPs case... as he accepted an answer that does the same thing.