# printing a char array backwards c++ using loops

Tags: c++, arrays

i am trying to print an array of unknown length backwards so wrote that the loop should start at the terminator and go to the first letter printing each letter but it keeps printing only the first

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char word[10];
    int i;

    cout << "Enter a word: " ;
    cin >> word;

    for ( word[i]= '\0'; word[1] <0; word[i] --)
    {
        cout << word[i] << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is uninitialized.

Comment: i is uninitialized. If it was initialized, go through your code step by step and try to figure e out what it would be doing. Just write it down, step by step.

Comment: @Marged this is not a duplicate, since the OP wants to print a char array backwards. (not a std::string)

Comment: @oo_miguel So I picked the wrong one ... But my point was: such relatively easy questions are likely not unique. Is this one better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647146/reverse-a-character-array ;-)

Comment: @Marged: yes I think this one is a duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 5):

You can print you C-style string backwards whith this one-liner:

```
reverse_copy(word,word+strlen(word),ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

Also *please* consider using `std::string`:

```
string word;
cin >> word;

copy(word.rbegin(),word.rend(),ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

You will need to `#include` the following headers for the above examples to work:

```
<algorithm>, <iostream>, <iterator>, <string> and <cstring>
```

Comment: As much as beginners should use `std::string`, this doesn't answer the question, which is about arrays.

Comment: @NeilKirk: fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your loop it does nothing:

```
for (i= strlen(word); i >=0; i--)
    {
        cout << word[i] << endl;  //endl is optional

    }
```

Also for in case of long strings you may have to increase size of char array or its better to use

```
string word;
for (i= word.size(); i >=0; i--)
        {
            cout << word[i] << endl;  //endl is optional

        }
```

Comment: This will work most of the time, but is not a perfect solution as it would not work with huge strings.

Comment: The issue with long strings is the type of `i` which is `int`, not the type storing the string.

Comment: @NeilKirk if seriously long strings bothers you then i think size of array also matters and there are 1001 more solutions to the question i should answer all of them. I just answerd based on question which was to provide assistance to the code ,and not just provide the optimal solution (for what google is also present).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to print a C-style string backwards.

```
for (size_t i = 0, i_end = std::strlen(word); i != i_end; ++i)
{
    std::cout << word[i_end - i - 1];
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Note that I save the result of `strlen` so that it is not called every time.

Comment: @wrangler I changed to a simpler technique.

Answer (score -2):

To get the result you want, you might want to use this code...

```
char word[10];
int sz; 

do {
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;
    sz = strlen(word);

} while (sz > 10);


for (int i = sz; i >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << word[i];

}
```

Comment: What if the input has less (or, in case of a buffer overflow, more) than 10 characters? Also note that `word[9]` is the last possible location in the array where a null byte is legally placed, so printing `word[9]` doesn't make much sense.