# Array Reverse - XOR slower than switching with temporary object

Tags: c++, algorithm, xor

I was reading a question regarding the fastest way to reverse an array (which ended up being less than thrilling), and I came across an interesting comment located at the link here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129028/857994

The solution referenced shows these two possibilities:

```
//Possibility #1
void reverse(char word[])
{
    int len=strlen(word);
    char temp;
    for (int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
            temp=word[i];
            word[i]=word[len-i-1];
            word[len-i-1]=temp;
    }
}

//Possibility #2
void reverse(char word[])
{
    int len=strlen(word);
    for (int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
        word[i]^=word[len-i-1];
        word[len-i-1]^=word[i];
        word[i]^=word[len-i-1];
    }
}
```

and the comment states: "Using XOR will be far slower than swapping using a temp object."

Nobody disputed this. So, my questions are:

1. Is this true?
2. Why is it true?
3. Would it still be true if this was an array of a non-built-in-type?

Comment: This is mentioned in the wikipedia article [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). Quote:`One reason is that modern CPUs strive to execute instructions in parallel via instruction pipelines. In the XOR technique, the inputs to each operation depend on the results of the previous operation, so they must be executed in strictly sequential order. If efficiency is of tremendous concern, it is advised to test the speeds of both the XOR technique and temporary variable swapping on the target architecture.` Also, temps can be optimized away by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xor loop contains 2 memory reads and 1 memory write per line, for a total of 6 reads and 3 writes for each loop iteration.  Furthermore, there is a strong dependency between the first line the writes to word[i] and the next line that reads from word[i].  This will prevent pipelining, or if the two lines execute in parallel, the second line's read from word[i] will stall until the first line's write is complete. There is another such dependency between the 2nd and 3rd lines.

In the temp var loop, the temp var will almost certainly be stored in a CPU register, not in main memory.  So the total memory I/O count for the temp var loop is 2 reads and 2 writes. There are loose data flow dependencies between the statements, but they are read-before-write which can be pipelined.  The data flow dependencies in the xor example are read-after-write, which are much harder to do without stalling the pipeline.

6 reads + 3 writes compared to 2 reads + 2 writes.  2 + 2 has a distinct advantage.

Comment: Why would the temporary be stored in a register (I agree), and not do so in the XOR case? It should just load the two values into registers and then operate there to write back only after the swaps completes. On the other hand, the pipelining is a good reason.

Comment: There is no possibility that the local temp variable could be read by unknown external parties, so enregistering the temp var is safe.  The compiler has complete knowledge of what has access to the temp var.  With the XOR memory write loop, writing to global memory makes the assignment visible outside of the compiler's immediate domain of control. Optimizations that eliminate writes to global memory are extremely dangerous and likely to break code. Because global memory writes are visible outside the compiler's domain of control, they should be considered sacred.