# Reverse of array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, reverse, swap

```
int main()
{
    int num[5];
    int num2[5];
    int n;
    int j = 0;
    cout << "provide size of array" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i =0; i< n; i++){
        cin >> num[i];
    }
    cout << "the size of n is " << n << endl;
    while(n != 0){
        num2[j] = num[n-1];
        n--;
        j++;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k< 5; k++){
        cout << num2[k] << endl;
    }
}
```

I need to create program for reversing the array, but without swap, I have done this but this is an optimal way  or using swap() is optimal ? as in swap I don't required to create another array.

Comment: You mean you cannot use `std::swap()` or you can't do any swap at all?

Comment: no, not using swap(), but still which is best way, using swap() or this one, as You can see i am able to reverse this array without swap().

Comment: Universal optimums do not exist. Optimal is always relatively to context or frame of reference. Often most optimal is not to reverse container at all but just iterate over it in reverse direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Reverse Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128985/c-reverse-array)

Comment: thanks @ÖöTiib i got ur point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use swap, you could use addition and subtraction instead

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void reverse( int* arr, unsigned n ) {
    if ( n==0 ) return;
    unsigned i=0;
    unsigned j=n-1;
    for ( ; i<j; i++,j-- ) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
        arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<int,5> values{1,2,3,4,5};
    reverse( &values[0], values.size() );
    for ( int val : values ) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/MrW8cEzPs

Result:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout

5 4 3 2 1
```